# Advice to help a friend out with her finances

Tags: bank-account, scams

A lady friend overseas at the moment, got robbed the other day. And asked for my acct info to make deposits into my acct and me withdraw them out and moneygram them back to her...is it safe?

Comment: This is a scam. Cut all contact with this person. They are scamming you.

Comment: Can you clarify "lady friend"?

Answer (score 12):

No, it's almost assuredly a scam.  The transfers she makes to you will eventually get reversed but the transfers you make to her are permanent.  So you'll be left on the hook to make up the difference to your bank.

It also doesn't make sense.  It's far easier for her to simply open her own account at her own bank in her own country and manage her own finances rather than to have everything routed through a different person at a different bank in a different country.